# Efficiently compute the i-th element of the sequence 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 8, ... in O(1)

Tags: algorithm, math

So there is this question that gives the following output for some input:

`2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, ...` for input

`n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, ...`

The first initial thought was of course to use DP to store the answers up to the constraint of the input (`n = 500000`) and just retrieve the answers from the array that has been generated.

However, seeing the numbers above causes me to think that this might be a sequence that can be answered by using some mathematical formula (usually `O(1)`, thus not having to resort to DP (which takes `O(n)` to generate, but `O(1)` to retrieve). Is there a way that I can formulate a formula to get the value of the `i`-th element with `i` being the input given by the user?

Comment: This is 2x sequence [A002260](https://oeis.org/A002260) in OEIS. I was hoping to find a O(1) solution that does not use square root, but no luck. Still, next time you have to find a formula of a sequence, start from OEIS.

Comment: @Dialecticus Excuse my ignorance, but why do you want to avoid square root? Also, I did stumble on that OEIS when I was trying to figure out another sequence, but it seems very complicated and I was intidimidated...

Comment: Working with floating point numbers is tied with error, however minuscule it may be. At some value `n` this sqrt math will produce an error, but we don't know where in advance.

Comment: @Dialecticus: In many programming languages you *do* know where in advance the `sqrt` function will fail to give a correct answer. I now work in Python 3 and I wrote a `isqrt` function which uses Python's `sqrt` up to a certain value (`2**50`) where it is correct. Above that value I use a slower method that works for all integer values, even Python's extended ones. I'm sure this can be done in other languages.

Comment: OK, I have changed my downvote. I know that self-answered questions are very difficult to do well on this site. I recently considered doing one myself but asked for feedback in meta. The feedback convinced me not to do it--I instead edited an old question (from someone else) and answered that.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thank you. I think that it's fine to ask self-answered questions. If the feedback is very bad, then you can simply delete the post, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can manipulate the above sequence into a sequence of groups, i.e.:

`2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 8, ...`

into

`1, 2, 3, 4, ...` with each number in this sequence denoting the **amount** of members in its group.

The idea here is to categorise the `i`-th element into a group. Once we've found its group, we can subtract **amount of previous group** elements from **`i`** giving us the precise location of its **position relative to its own group** (e.g. the second `4` in the sequence above is the 2nd element of the 3rd group). We know that the position of the element determines its value, that is we only need to multiply its position by 2. What this means is that if we can get its relative position in its group, we can find its value.

For example, the first `6` in the sequence above. It is inside group 3, relative position 3 and has the value 6. Given its position in the first sequence (i.e. position 6), how do we calculate its value? We can use the **formula of arithmetic sequence** on the **second** sequence (as it is arithmetic) to approximately count the `n` on the formula `Sn = n/2 * (2a + (n-1))`. After finding out the `n` value, if it's not a whole number, we know that there **is no way that the `n` is the rounded-down value**.

Calculation of the first `6` in the sequence above to find its group:

```
Sn = n/2 * (2a + (n-1))
6 * 2 = n * (2 + n - 1)
12 = n^2 + n
0 = n^2 + n - 12
```

From there, we can calculate the **positive** `n` using the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula), which is `n = (-b+sqrt(b^2-4ac)/2a)`.

```
n = [-1 + sqrt(1-4*1*-22)]/2
n = [-1 + sqrt(89)]/2
n = 2.9278273
```

We will round this `n` up to 3 and now we know that the first `6` is of group `3`. To find its position relative in its group, we can simply subtract the amount of elements in the previous groups **from** `i`. To find the amount of elements in the previous groups, we can utilise the same arithmetic sequence formula, albeit with `n` being `3 - 1` (as we are calculating the amount of members in the previous group).

```
S2 = 2/2 * (2 + 2 - 1)
S2 = 3
```

Knowing that there are 3 members before the `i`-th element, we can subtract `3` from `i` (6) to yielding 3 (it's relative position in its group). Then, we can find its value my multiplying by 2 therefore attaining 6.

Code in C++:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    double approximateN;
    int S_approximateNMinusOne;

    cin >> n;
    approximateN = ceil((sqrt(1 + 4 * n * 2) - 1.00) / 2.00);
    S_approximateNMinusOne = (approximateN - 1) * (2 + approximateN - 2) / 2.00;
    cout << (n - S_approximateNMinusOne) * 2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```